# Tell to linux binary where load shared libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a problem with shared libraries.
I have a binary linked with some shared libraries.
I have build all in c++ with gcc -L dirLibraries ecc ecc -llibraryName1 -libraryName2 ecc
Now if i launch my binary tell me that he can't find one library,
if i launch binary from another directory he tell me that can't find another library.
what i need to do for tell to my binary where need to load libraries independently the location where I launch the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two environment variables which may help:

1. `LD_RUN_PATH` is used during building to configure a set of locations to be searched when looking for shared libraries.
2. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used when running the program to add additional pathes to be searched for shared libraries.

How the environment variables are set depends somewhat on the enviroment you are using. If you are using a shell like `bash` or `ksh` you can use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path:/another/path:/as/many/as/you/need
```

Following it, programs started from this shell will inherit the environment variable (you might want to also look at the relevant document, e.g., [bash's documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)).

If you are using some sort of IDE you might need to set the environment variables from your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: exaclty you can explain to me how and where i need to set there envoirment variables please?

Comment: @pava91: I have expanded the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the shared libraries you want to load on the library search path or add the directories containing them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See also [Shared Libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), esp. "Section 3.2. How Libraries are Used" and "Section 3.3.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH".